# Analyze long documents with OpenAI Assistant

Tags: python, web, openai-api

I hope everyone's doing good.
I am currently using OpenAI's assistant to process documents and extract relevant information from them. The documents are long (about 45 pages, 44k words approximately). I am going to integrate this into a web app for users to use. I have some questions about that.
If I use a single assistant, then multiple users will upload files and it will mix the information from multiple documents and give inaccurate information to users. There's also the problem of tokens. As the documents are quite long, the daily token limit will be reached very quickly. How would I go about solving this. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Tried the OpenAI Assistant python API with gpt-4-1106-preview model. It was pretty accurate but need help with integrating it into a web app.

Comment: What help do you need?  Please describe where your stuck.

Comment: There are some specific fields that I would like to extract from files. Whenever a user uploads their file, the specific fields will be extracted from it and presented to the user. It won't be like a chatbot where the user can ask questions. But I need ideas as to how to integrate this into a web app because the app will be used by many users and multiple files will be uploaded.

Comment: So you need a way for users to log in and a database to store data for the user. That is still very broad.  What framework are you using for this web app?  What tech stack?

Comment: ASP .Net. But I am looking to do this with Python and then integrate it there

Answer (score 0):

OpenAI's Assistant API has a [limit of 20 files per Assistant](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files).

Given this, you may be spawning a separate Assistant per user session. Users will be limited to 20 files.

Daily token limits are computed based on your spend ($$$).

Answer (score -1):

As of this day, it is not yet possible to build something like you're describing using only OpenAI.

If you want to be able to communicate with files in your context you should look into creating a system that parses files, normalises them, converts them to vectors and makes them available to be stored in vector databases (e.g. Pinecone) that will later be used for retrieving that knowledge. This way you won't have the potential problem of document interference cause you will glue the files in the database to a specific user. In this situation you don't even need Asssitants API, a text generation API will be enough.